# Обнуление кортежа в Python после применения sum

Tags: python

Вот так вывод кортежа происходит нормально:

```
l = (i for i in range(1,9) if i%2 == 1)
print(*l)
```

Получаем на выводе 1 3 5 7

Но если попытаться сначала вывести сумму кортежа, то сумма выведется, но сам кортеж уже не отобразится:

```
l = (i for i in range(1,9) if i%2 == 1)
print(sum(l))
print(*l)
```

На выводе получим 16 и пустую строку.

Если делать то же самое не с кортежем, а со списком, то все нормально. В чем причина странного поведения кортежа?

Comment: В том, что это не кортеж, а генератор

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию @andreymal: попробуйте в REPL запустить `l = (i for i in range(1,9) if i%2 == 1); l`. Интерпретатор покажет тип объекта (на моей машине, например, `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4a09a5fe08>`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конструкция `... for ... in ...` в круглых скобках порождает не кортеж, а генератор — объект, который используется для итерации всяких последовательностей. Ключевое отличие от списка — непосредственные вычисления производятся только по мере надобности, при получении каждого следующего элемента вызовом функции [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). Итератор одноразовый  однажды получив все значения, он будет пуст. Собственно говоря, это у вас и происходит вначале при вычислении суммы, затем уже ничего не остаётся для вывода на экран.

Давайте рассмотрим пример.

```
l = [2**i for i in range(2, 10)]
g = (2**i for i in range(2, 10))
```

В первом случае все возведения в степень будут произведены в момент создания списка, а все созданные числа будут храниться в памяти. Может быть не очень рационально, если они будут использоваться только по одному разу.

Во втором случае, напротив, операция возведения в степень производится непосредственно в момент получения очередного элемента. Например, так

```
next(g)  # вернёт 4 при первом вызове, затем 8 при втором, ...
```

Когда последовательность заканчивается, вызов [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) окончится исключением [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration). Это даёт однозначно выявить конец.

Comment: Все итераторы в Питоне "одноразовые". Если next выбросит StopIteration хоть однажды (чтобы конец обозначить), то по [протоколу итератора next обязан продолжать выбрасывать StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__)

Answer (score 4):

Преобразование [генератора](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) в кортеж спасёт отца русской демократии

```
l = tuple(i for i in range(1,9) if i%2 == 1)
```